# To contemplate one's navel for cosmic significance

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't know if this is a real word, but when I was in high school my teacher had a Word-a-Day vocabulary calendar. She read us a word one day with a definition of "To contemplate one's navel for cosmic significance" or something similar. I forget the word, and have not found it since.

Seems like I remember the word starting with an 'O'.

Does this word exist? What is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like ***navel-gazing*** to me.

> –noun *Slang.*
>   excessive absorption in
>   self-analysis or focus on a single
>   issue.

**Edit:** Starting with an 'O', I'll go with ***omphaloskepsis***. It's the fancy Greek term for navel-gazing :).

> –noun
>   contemplation of one's navel as part of a mystical exercise.

Comment: Seems like I remember the word starting with an 'O'. I added that to the question. I don't recall it having 'navel' in the word either. Thanks though!

Comment: Ah, then I suggest omphaloskepsis. Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: Ah, that does appear to be what I remember! Thanks!